# boost::asio::async_write invalid arguments

Tags: c++, boost-asio

i've the following c++ function :

```
int Asio_Send_Pck(int iSendt,int Lsocket,char * Lbuff,int Len)
{
    session* iTempSession = reinterpret_cast<session*>(Lsocket);
    boost::asio::async_write(iTempSession->socket() ,
                              boost::asio::buffer(Lbuff, Len),
                              boost::bind(&session::handle_write, 
                              iTempSession,
                              boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                              iTempSession->data,
                              iSendt
                              ));
    return 0;
};
```

But when compiling i get an Invalid arguments error on **async_write** , can i know where's ( are these ) this invalid argument(s) .

PS : I work with **Boost Version 1.67.0** .

Answer (score 0):

In first argument you have `>` instead of `->` and it makes type of first argument to be `bool` (result of comparison) instead of needed type (probably some stream).

Comment: thank you it was a typo error the correct is with `->` .

Comment: Thank you psur that was not the solution .